# what does the error "missing right parenthesis" in oracle sql means

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run this code and it seems correct to me but I'm getting an error stating that there's a right parenthesis missing.

The code is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_ID     INT NOT NULL,
    NAME            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH   DATE,
    PHONE_NB        CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(50),
    TOTAL_SPENDING  FLOAT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,

    PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMER_ID)
);
```

Can anyone help me in solving my problem?

Comment: I'm no Oracle expert, but I'm thinking that the `DEFAULT 0.0` should come before the `NOT NULL`. These *"Missing Right Parentheses"* errors in the CREATE TABLE DDL in Oracle are almost always a syntax error like that.

Comment: The standard string type is **`VARCHAR2`**, not `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`. Don't use `CHAR` unless you actually want values to be blank-padded (which, trust me, nobody does).

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged SQL Developer...

...the tool tries to give you a heads-up there will be a problem before you even hit the Execute button

[image]

The default value for the column is confusing the parser because it's not expected at that point.

Move it to after the data type and you'll be good

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
    customer_id      INT NOT NULL,
    name             VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    date_of_birth    DATE,
    phone_nb         CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    address          VARCHAR(50),
    total_spending   FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( customer_id )
);
```

PS In oracle, use VARCHAR2, not VARCHAR. While VARCHAR will 'work', it's reserved and could mean something different in a future release.

Comment: Just a comment: CUSTOMER_ID doesn't have to be set to NOT NULL as it is a primary key column, and primary keys don't allow NULLs anyway.

Comment: @Littlefoot nice catch :)

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I work with people who are pretty vague about the three properties of a primary key (unique, not null, unchanging). As such, I often include a NOT NULL constraint on a primary key, just to ram home the idea that NULLs are not allowed in this column.

Comment: It doesn't hurt anything, probably

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong order of column definition clauses: the constraint (`NOT NULL`) should follow the default value.

This is the right way:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_ID     INT NOT NULL,
    NAME            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH   DATE,
    PHONE_NB        CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS         VARCHAR(50),
    TOTAL_SPENDING  FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY(CUSTOMER_ID)
);
```